# Json-rpc service on java for jquery terminal emulator

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, json-rpc, jquery-terminal

I want to write web service that provides web-terminal for remote processing custom commands.
I found this jquery plugin http://terminal.jcubic.pl/. It needs JSON-RPC service.
As server side i want to use java web app built on spring-mvc framework. 
I am new in Java EE and Spring and don't know what it is better to use for this task. Can you advice me something?

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries for JSON-RPC in Java http://json-rpc.org/wiki/implementations#Java you can use one of them.

**UPDATE**: I wrote blog post how to create JSON-RPC servlet ["Ready to use json-rpc servlet in java"](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/ready-to-use-json-rpc-servlet-in-java/)